# Referencing current cell, but from different worksheet

Tags: google-sheets, cell

I'm making two spreadsheets in Google Sheets / Excel, where I want to reference the current cell, but in a different spreadsheet.

So I want cell A1 from worksheet 1 to be mirrored in A1 in worksheet 2, B1 from worksheet 1 to be mirrored in B1 in worksheet 2, and so on.

I thought this might work, but it doesn't

```
=CELL(speadsheet1!THIS_CELL)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel:

If your other sheet does not have spaces in the name:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&CELL("address"))
```

If it does have a space:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet 2'!"&CELL("address"))
```

Edit: In Google Sheets, try:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&address(row(),column()))
```

Comment: @Kaosmos What is the sheet name of the sheet you're referencing? If you go to Formula Evaluator, where does it error out?

Comment: The sheet is named "Data", so I put in: =INDIRECT("Data!"&CELL("address")) 

I can't use formula evaluator, since I'm in Google Sheets, I think?

Comment: @Kaosmos - Ah, didn't realize you needed it in Google Sheets. I'm not familiar with it, but try `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&address(row(),column()))`

Comment: There we go! Thank you so much, @BruceWayne ! :D